# Is this succulent vine? Or some another plant?

Tags: identification, succulents, vines

What plant is this and does it grow in water only?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is peperomia obtusifolia, AKA baby rubber plant.

They can grow in water too and need to have only few nodes in water.

They like moderate to bright indirect light and are very resilient to pests. Soil needs to dry out completely before watering.

https://www.joyusgarden.com/repotting-peperomia-plants/

Image from Plantsrescew:

[image]

Comment: If this is not the right answer, kindly notify.